# How can I train tensorflow deeplab model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, semantic-segmentation, deeplab

I need to train tensorflow deeplab model with my shoes dataset. Then i will use this model in order to remove background of image shoe. How could i train it ? Could you explain step by step ? You have any example for this situation ?
[tensorflow/deeplab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab)

Comment: Please describe what you have tried already.

Answer (score 2):

You will need read some parts of Deeplab code

- Download repo
- Now you need to put your data in tfrecord in proper format
- Use some of scripts in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab/datasets to download and generate example datasets
- Prepare analogous script for your shoes dataset
- Add information about data to Deeplab source file https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/datasets/data_generator.py add info in analogous format like example datasets
- Check flags for architecture https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/common.py
- Check specific flags and then train, export, count statistics or visualize using `train.py`, `vis.py`, `export_model.py`, `eval.py` in folder https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab